# Passing and recieving multi-dimensional primitive (int) arrays in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array

I have two objective c methods. One needs to return an int[][] and the other which needs to take int[][] as a parameter. I was originally using an NSMutableArray with NSMutableArrays as values however I was told to redo it like this in order to be compatible with some current code. I can't figure out how to make this work. I'm not sure I'm even googling the right thing. Anyway here is what I have now.

```
+(int [][consantValue]) getCoefficients
{
    int coefficiennts [constantValue2][constantValue1] = { {0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8} };
    return coefficients;
}
```

At the return statement I get the Error "Array initilizer must be an initializer list'

I also have to take the int[][] and rebuild it into an NSMutableArray of NSMutableArrays in another method but I'm hoping if someone can give me a hint on the first part I can work the second part out myself although if anyone has any advice on that I would appreciate it as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to do this for fixed size array(s) is to use a struct for storage:

```
typedef struct {
 int at[constantValue2][constantValue1];
} t_mon_coefficients;
```

And then you'd declare the method which returns by value:

```
+ (t_mon_coefficients)coefficients;
```

And passes by value as a parameter:

```
- (void)setCoefficients:(const t_mon_coefficients)pCoefficients;
```

If the struct is large, you should pass by reference:

```
// you'd use this like:
//   t_mon_coefficients coef;
//   [SomeClass getCoefficients:&coef];
+ (void)getCoefficients:(t_mon_coefficients* const)pOutCoefficients;

- (void)setCoefficients:(const t_mon_coefficients*)pCoefficients;
```

But there are multiple ways one could accomplish this.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around this. I remember using structs in my c class years ago. I'm going to play around with this a bit and figure it out. One probably stupid question though: Why do you use the "t_mon_" to preface it?

Comment: @MichelleJS a) one problem with passing arrays around is ownership. it's by reference when using raw arrays, but you can use the struct and save yourself some woes because it can be passed by value. storage is easy to manage. as an example, `return coefficients;` in the OP returns a reference to a local variable (crash). b) it's good practice to prefix your types so they do not conflict with other types. so you might see "CG" for CoreGraphics structs (also opaque types), "NS" for Foundation structs, and also "NS" for objc types. "t_mon_" or "MON" is just how i prefix examples (like "MY*").

Comment: @MichelleJS and the problem that happens if there are 2 types with the same name in the same translation/scope is that the compiler will forbid it, just like `void f() {int a; char a;}` is not legal.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I never actually got it working but the guy who wanted it came back and changed his mind after he couldn't figure it out either. So I am going to mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @MichelleJS you're welcome -- which part are you having trouble with?